# How to read props from src/test/resources in src/main/java

Tags: java, xml, maven

I've standard maven project...

In `src/main/java` I've a class called `MyResourceLoader.java` that load some resource by name `my_props.xml`.

In `src/test/resource`, I've created this `my_props.xml`.

Now in `src/test/java`, I try to invoke the `MyResourceLoader.java`, but It cannot see `my_props.xml`..

How to make it visible ??

Comment: Please give us your code and/or stacktrace so we can actually diagnose the problem :)

Comment: try adding resources folder to build path although m2e plugin automatically do that

Comment: How do you run your test? By IDE? If so: What IDE? Or by maven call?

Comment: Thanks all, it was typo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
src/test/resources
```

Not

```
src/test/resource
```

Answer (score 0):

From @sotirios-delimanolis :

You put your resources in src/**test**/resources , and when you run it your aren't testing, you are running it, so maven compiles it and ignores the `src/test` directory.

Change it to `src/main/resources` and see if that fixes the problem, the `src/main` directotry is what is put into the actual jar.